# VB.NET and SQL INSERT INTO; data is truncated

Tags: sql, vb.net, executenonquery

I use VB.NET Studio Express 2012 to read a filestream into SQL Server Express. The database and table are created fine, most records load without error using `.ExecuteNonQuery INSERT INTO`, but some records I get the error:

> String or binary data would be truncated.

Originally this was correct, because the column was only 20 characters and the data was between 22-25 on the failing records. I have changed the table so the column now is 30 char, but the error is still the same. I dropped the database and recreated it, but still the same problem.

Does VB keep info on field length somewhere?

Comment: show the code that inserting data ..

Comment: Are you sure you aren't still trying to insert data that is longer than the column(s) length?

Answer (score 0):

May be some spaces are present before or after your string,you can use ***Trim()*** function and then try to insert.Trim function will remove extra  spaces placed before and after you string.